# Django: How to assign users one of three URLS at random?

Tags: python, django

I have a problem that I have been struggling with for a few days.

I need to assign users to one of three different surveys at random. Each survey is contained in a `SessionWizardView`. I have been trying to figure out how to assign the users when they click a start button which I have wrapped in a `<form>`

**start.html**

```
<form action="" method="get">
<a class="btn btn-success">START</a>
</form>
```

**urls.py**

My URLconf for the start page and for each of the SessionWizardViews

```
url(r'^start/$', survey_views.start),

url(r'^surveyone/$', SurveyWizardOne.as_view([SurveyFormA, SurveyFormB, SurveyFormC, SurveyFormD ])),
url(r'^surveytwo/$', SurveyWizardTwo.as_view([SurveyFormA, SurveyFormB, SurveyFormC, SurveyFormD ])),
url(r'^surveythree/$', SurveyWizardThree.as_view([SurveyFormA, SurveyFormB, SurveyFormC, SurveyFormD ])),
```

**views.py**

```
def start(request):
    return render(request, 'start.html')

class SurveyWizardOne(SessionWizardView):
    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):       
        return render_to_response('Return_to_AMT.html', {
            'form_data': [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],
        })

class SurveyWizardTwo(SessionWizardView):
    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):          
        return render_to_response('Return_to_AMT.html', {
            'form_data': [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],
        })

class SurveyWizardThree(SessionWizardView):
 def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):       
     return render_to_response('Return_to_AMT.html', {
         'form_data': [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],
     })
```

Im not really sure where to progress from here. I am totally confused by how to get the URL back to the user, I hope that makes sense. Im quite new to Django/Python and have never used an MCV framework before.

I would be able to figure out the random aspect of it as I have done stuff like this years ago in Java, but it was all in one self contained program. In this case I'm not even sure where it should go

Comment: Choose one at random and then return a 302 redirect to that view you chose with url for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either generate the random link in view code, or in template using built in django `random` template filter (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#random). Code below is for the first choice:

```
def start(request):
    survey_urls = ['/surveyone/', '/surveytwo/', '/surveythree/']
    survey_url = random.choice(surveys)
    return render(request, 'start.html', {'survey_url': survey_url})
```

And then in your template do the standard

```
<a class="btn btn-success" href="{{survey_url}}">START</a>
```

You can also consider giving your urls name parameter in urls.py and using `reverse` function(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#django.core.urlresolvers.reverse) so `survey_urls` list is not hardcoded.